# Force console to be open on load within iframe - chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to create some simple tutorials, which involve people using the console in chrome. Ideally I would like to build them in a codecademy style - so instead of saying 'browse to this element in the console' and the user having to go to a separate demo page and do this, it would be built into one page.

So, I would have the tutorial, and then an iframe containing the demo page. I need the console to be open in the iframe page (and stay contained within it), but still be usable.

I know in chrome you can change which iframe you are viewing in the dev tools, and if needs be I will simply instruct users to do that, but I feel it would be more effective / smoother if the console was actually within the iframe and was automatically there.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.